# Why would creating GUI elements through a ModuleScript fail when used through `Touched:Connect`

Tags: roblox

I have a ModuleScript that works, but it will not function when applied to my `lbcollide` function, even though the function itself does run.

ModuleScript:

```
local ScreenText = {}

count = 0
currentText = {}

function ScreenText.displayText(text)
    local label = newDisplay()
    label.Text= text
end
function newDisplay()
    count += 1
    for index = 1, #currentText do
        currentText[index].Position += UDim2.new(0,0,0,50)
        currentText[index].Transparency += .1
    end
    if count >5 then
        currentText[1]:Destroy()
        table.remove(currentText,1)
        count -=1
    end
    local label = Instance.new("TextLabel",game.StarterGui.ScreenGui)
    label.Visible = true
    label.Size = UDim2.new(0,300,0,50)
    label.Position = UDim2.new(.5,-150,0,0)
    label.Transparency = 0
    label.TextSize= 24
    label.BackgroundColor3 = Color3.new(0,0,0)
    label.BorderSizePixel = 1
    label.BorderMode = 0
    label.BorderColor3 = Color3.new(255,75,75)
    label.TextColor = BrickColor.new(1,1,1)
    table.insert(currentText,label)
    return label
end
return ScreenText
```

Attempted Use:

```
local textService = require(game.ServerScriptService.ScreenText)

local part = script.Parent
local debounce = 0

textService.displayText("A")
textService.displayText("B")


function lbCollide(otherPart)
    if debounce == 0 then
        debounce = 1
        if otherPart.Parent:FindFirstChild("Humanoid") then
            print("MAKE")
            textService.displayText("Touching block!")
        end
    end
end

local function lbDebounce(otherPart)
    --debounce = 0
end

part.Touched:Connect(lbCollide)
part.TouchEnded:Connect(lbDebounce)
```

The ScreenText module works, but not for the line "Touching Block!" The print statement works, and adding the "A" and "B" work.